# Debugging Step By Step Trinary Search

Tags: python, search

Here's my code.

```
def trin_search(A,first,last,target):
    #returns index of target in A, if present
    #returns -1 if target is not present in A
    if first>last:
        return -1
    else:
        one_third=first+(last-first/3)
        two_thirds=first+2*(last-first)/3
        if A[one_third]==target:
            return one_third
        elif A[one_third]>target:
            #search the left-hand third
            return trin_search(A,first, one_third-1],target)
        elif A[two_thirds]==target:
            return two_thirds
        elif A[two_thirds]>target:
            #search the middle third
            return trin_search(A,one_third+1,two_thirds-1,target)
        else:
            #search the right-hand third
            return trin_search(A,two_thirds+1,last,target)
```

It's a trinary recursive search. I keep getting this error:

```
line 24, in trin_search
if A[one_third]==target:IndexError: list index out of range
```

but I can't imagine why. Here's how I'm running the program in the shell:

```
>>>> A=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
>>>> trin_search(A,A[0],A[len(A)-1],5)
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Sorry accidentally submitted before I was finished editing.

Comment: Have you tried printing the function arguments from inside the function call to see which recursive call is generating the error?

Comment: Not meaning to be rude, but "debugging step by step" is something _you_ should do. When you've narrowed it down as much as you can, and if you still don't understand the problem, it's time to post a question (imho).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the line `one_third=first+(last-first/3)`. Here, `first == 1` so `first/3 == 0` and the expression becomes `first+last`, which is 21 and so clearly out of range. The expression you want is `first+(last-first)/3`. (There are some other problems in your code as well, such as calling the function with the values from the list instead of the indices.)

Comment: Yeah, a function like this is usually set up to default `first` and `last` to `0` and `len(A)` respectively, to make it easier to use for the basic case.